# No Client Token found, please set the Client Token

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to create the login with facebook in android and I am running into this issue. I am not sure what else I am failing to see or set.

I tried setting app toke / client secret but it keeps failing.

Below is my code: 
**Manifest file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.test.app">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FacebookLoginActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.FACEBOOK_LOGIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
            tools:replace="android:theme" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAINACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**FacebookLoginActivity**

```
 package com.test.app;
    public class FacebookLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private TextView info;

        private LoginButton loginButton;
        private CallbackManager callbackManager;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
            super.onCreate(bundle);
            FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

            callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
            setContentView(R.layout.facebook_login);
            info = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
            loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

            loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    info.setText(
                            "User ID: "
                                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                                    + "\n" +
                                    "Auth Token: "
                                    + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
                    );
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        }
    }
```

**ERROR**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No Client Token found, please set the Client Token.
                      at com.facebook.internal.Validate.hasClientToken(Validate.java:162)
                      at com.facebook.login.DeviceAuthDialog.startLogin(DeviceAuthDialog.java:178)
                      at com.facebook.login.DeviceAuthMethodHandler.showDialog(DeviceAuthMethodHandler.java:51)
                      at com.facebook.login.DeviceAuthMethodHandler.tryAuthorize(DeviceAuthMethodHandler.java:42)
                      at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.tryCurrentHandler(LoginClient.java:254)
                      at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.tryNextHandler(LoginClient.java:216)
                      at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.authorize(LoginClient.java:121)
                      at com.facebook.login.LoginClient.startOrContinueAuth(LoginClient.java:102)
                      at com.facebook.login.LoginFragment.onResume(LoginFragment.java:153)
                      at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2230)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1343)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1523)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1585)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:2842)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:223)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
                      at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
                      at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6807)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3406)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3469) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2732) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
```

Comment: Does your `@string/facebook_app_id` has proper value?

Comment: Yes. <string name="facebook_app_id">********</string>.

I tried setting this manually too but then login fails.

Comment: in which line you are getting exception

Comment: try adding android:exported="true" in com.facebook.FacebookActivity of manifest file

Comment: same error... this is the line where it fails: 
String accessToken = Validate.hasAppID()+ "|" + Validate.hasClientToken();

Comment: did use com.facebook.login.widget.DeviceLoginButton or com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton in your layout cause the former is the one that generates this error

Comment: @behinddwalls did you fix it ?

Comment: Nopes..Didn't get it working..

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to add your app client token to your AndroidManifest like this:

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ClientToken"
        android:value="@string/facebook_client_token"/>
```

You can find your app client token in facebook dashboard -> settings -> advanced (in the security section)

Comment: could you tell me why we should add app secret ?

Answer (score 0):

in the login button cross check
`<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton` -> this is right
`<com.facebook.login.widget.DeviceLoginButton` -> this is wrong